# How to get the output data from R script in node using r-script

Tags: r, node.js, npm

I am trying to execute a R script from node.js using [r-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/r-script) because it looks pretty simple.

With the documentation example:

**example.js**

```
var out = R("ex-sync.R")
  .data("hello world", 20)
  .callSync();

console.log(out);
```

**ex-sync.R**

```
needs(magrittr)
set.seed(512)
do.call(rep, input) %>% 
  strsplit(NULL) %>% 
  sapply(sample) %>% 
  apply(2, paste, collapse = "")
```

My out variable which supposed to be the last line of R script, is always null and I have no idea why this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users:

You need to add the environment variable to Windows's %PATH% variable. R-script package needs to call "R" command from the CMD. If R.exe is not set as an environment variable, then it will never be able to call the "R" command from anywhere.

Look up how to add environment variables to Windows, and remember: if the path to the folder containing the executables has a white space, it must be added to double quotes. "C:\Program Files\R\R-**`version`**\bin\x64"
**** replace version**

If you have already done this but the problem persists, I can only think of two reasons:

There's something wrong with your R method and it's giving an internal exception inside the R session.

The system can't find the file. Maybe check the file path.